# Different parametric forms of a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

One of the standard equations for a rectangular "reciprocal" hyperbola which is in the $1$st and $3$rd quadrants is
$$xy=c^2$$

And its corresponding parametric equations are $x = ct$ and $y = \frac{c}{t}$, where $t$ can be any real number, except $0$.

Another standard form of the rectangular hyperbola is "horizontal" or "left-right", i.e. where the its transverse axis is $\parallel$ to the $x$-axis. Its equations can be derived by rotating the "reciprocal" hyperbola ($xy=c^2$) clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\pi}{4} & \sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\ -\sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} ct \\ \frac{c}{t} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{ct\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{c\sqrt{2}}{2t} \\ \frac{c\sqrt{2}}{2t} - \frac{ct\sqrt{2}}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

So the parametric equations are

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x = \frac{ct\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{c\sqrt{2}}{2t} \\
y = \frac{c\sqrt{2}}{2t} - \frac{ct\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

However, the parametric equations can also be [derived geometrically](http://www.nabla.hr/PC-Hyperbola3.htm) in an alternative form:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x = a \sec t \\
y = a \tan t
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Where (I believe) $a = c\sqrt{2}$. How can we show the equivalence of these forms or use one to derive another algebraically?

Comment: Your first parametric form is incorrect. The $t$ denominators should be $2t$. ... One way to show the two forms are equivalent is to show that each is equivalent to the Cartesian form $x^2-y^2=a^2\;(=2c^2)$.

Comment: @Blue I have corrected the error. I can show the first parametric form is equal to $x^2-y^2=a^2$, but I could use some help with the second form.

Comment: @Mihael, substitute $\displaystyle\theta\to\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$ in $(a\sec\theta, a\tan\theta)$ to get $(ct, \frac{c}{t})$.